# How to Test Receiving Email With Attachment Using Google App Engine Debug Server

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm using the Eclipse 3.6 development environment with the Google Plugin for Eclipse. I created a web project and configured it to receive email following the instructions at the link below.

I would like to test receiving an email with an attachment. There is an email sending simulator as described below. Does anyone have an update to this simulator that includes attaching files so I can simulate receiving an email with an attachment.

Note: My deployed app receives email with attachments just fine. My goal is to be able to test receiving emails with attachments in a test environment. Otherwise I can't step through the code.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving.html

"Once you set up your app to handle incoming email, you can use the development server console to simulate incoming email messages. You can access the development server by going to localhost:8888/_ah/admin/ (or if your app is running on a port other than 8888, use that value instead). In the development server, click Inbound Mail on the left side, fill out the form that appears, and click Send Email. "

Answer (score 1):

You can't test email with attachment using Google App Engine development server.
Have a look to [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2813) feature request.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a python script to simulate sending attachments:

```
import os, sys
import requests
import urllib2
import urlparse

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import formatdate
from email import Encoders

def post_mail(url, send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[]):
    assert isinstance(files, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = send_to
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

    for f in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
        msg.attach(part)

    m = msg.as_string()
    print send_to
    u = urlparse.urljoin(url, "/_ah/mail/" + urllib2.quote(send_to))
    print u
    requests.post(u, data=m, headers={'content-type':'multipart/alternative'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 6:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: test_mail.py urlbase fromaddr toaddr subject body file1 [..filen]"
        print >> sys.stderr, 'E.g. test_mail.py http://localhost:8080 test@example.com something@appname.appspotmail.com "Sample Subject" "Sample Body" file1.csv file2.csv'
        sys.exit(1)

    url = sys.argv[1]
    sender = sys.argv[2]
    receiver = sys.argv[3]
    subject = sys.argv[4]
    body = sys.argv[5]
    files = sys.argv[6:]

    post_mail(url, sender, receiver, subject, body, files)
```

In your `app.yaml` route handlers, you might need to comment out the `login: admin` for the mail route when testing in the local development server.

Comment: With the most recent version of the ```email``` module the imports are slightly different.  `from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import Encoders`